# ggplot2 geom_line colors by group but with different colorcodes

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

does anyone know how I can plot several line graphs in one graph with different color codes?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable1)) +
geom_line(aes(y=variable2,color=group1))+
geom_line(aes(y=variable3,color=group1))
```

I would like to have one color code for the first geom_line and a different one for the second geom_line.

```
color_group <- c("blue","black","yellow2","orange")
color_flag <- c("green","red","yellow2","cyan")
```

With

```
 scale_colour_manual(values=color_group)
```

I can only assign a color code to both of them simultaneously and not separately. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: It looks like you could pivot your y axis variables into long format to achieve this. If you're stuck on how to do that, please include some reproducible data we can use to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ggnewscale` package

```
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = variable2, color = group1)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = color_group) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(y = variable3, color = group1)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = color_flag)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it out a bit and it works like intended. Now I can plot sets of linear graphs with two different axis/ scales (one on the left and one on the right) and by changing the colors of the line graphs separately I can visualize to which scale they belong!  :)